# Invariant mesures for expanding maps of the circle

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Is there any characterization for the support of T-invariant measures? where T is a C¹ expanding map of the circle i.e. T'(x)>Lambda>1 for all x in the circle.

I know there are periodic and total support measures but what about the rest of ergodic invariant measures?

Comment: I don't understand... how can $T:\mathbb{S}^1\to \mathbb{S}^1$ have $T'(x)>1$ for all $x$ ?

Comment: Even for the $\times p$ map, there are very wild sets who are the support for an invariant and ergodic measure, basically you can get Cantor sets of every possible dimension.

Comment: @PietroMajer: let $T$ have degree two or higher, for example $T \colon \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $T(x):=2x \mod \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: ah, ok thanks  -I assumed T was a diffeo :)

Comment: Excuse me,@IanMorris but I have another question:  Is it  truth that if x has a dense positive orbit and $x$ generates an ergodic measure $\mu_x=\lim \frac{1}{n}\sum \delta_{T^jx}$ then its support is total?

Comment: @chaut: no, this is false. Let $T$ be the $\times 2$ map, and let $(u_n)$ be an enumeration of the dyadic rationals. Take $x = (0.u_1 v_1 u_2 v_2...)$, where the $v_n$ are finite sequences of $0$. Then, if the length of the $v_n$ grow fast enough, the orbit of $x$ spends most of its time close to $0$, so $\mu_x = \delta_0$. The orbit of $x$ will still be dense, as it goes very close to each dyadic rational.